Show routeline above my Overlay tiles in NavigationMapView - MapBoxMaps
I am trying to achieve requirement like - Help user for Turn-By-Turn Navigation between 2 locations using NavigationViewController of mapbox-maps-navigation.
Over the NavigationMapView, i add tiles Overlay, and i want to show routeline over that Tile overlay.
Using my below code, My source and destination pin is showing on overlay, But not Routeline:
    func addRasterSource(for mapView: NavigationMapView) {
        let sourceId = "raster-source"
        let sourceUrl = "URL-FOR_TILE_OVERLAY"
        var rasterSource = RasterSource(id: sourceId)
        rasterSource.tiles = [sourceUrl]
        rasterSource.tileSize = 256 //.above("pitch-outline")
        let rasterLayer = RasterLayer(id: "raster-layer", source: sourceId)
        let layerPosition = getLayerPositionBelowNavigation(for: mapView)

        do {
            try mapView.mapView.mapboxMap.addSource(rasterSource)
            try mapView.mapView.mapboxMap.addLayer(rasterLayer, layerPosition: layerPosition)
            
        } catch {
            print("Failed to update the style. Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

func getLayerPositionBelowNavigation(for mapView: NavigationMapView) -> LayerPosition {
        // Fetch all layers from the style
        guard let layers = try? mapView.mapView.mapboxMap.style.allLayerIdentifiers else {
            return .above("pitch-outline")
        }
        
        if let routeLayer = layers.first(where: { $0.id.contains("navigation")}) {
            return .below(routeLayer.id) //.below(routeLayer.id)
        }
        
        return .above("water")
    }

